# Пунктуация в предложении со словом «согласно»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Согласно указанному акту расследования организацией, виновной в аварии является ПАО "АБ", которой поручено проведение противоаварийных мероприятий.

Проверьте, пожалуйста, пунктуацию.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно указанному акту расследования, организацией, виновной в аварии, является ПАО «АБ», которой (было?) поручено проведение противоаварийных мероприятий.

Comment: ***Почему*** именно так?

Comment: Спасибо, а не могли бы пояснить первую запятую?

Comment: Здесь запятая, поскольку источник информации.